# Renaming files with same file name pattern in Unix server using shell script

Tags: shell, unix, scripting, rename, filenames

I have a few files with the same file name pattern in the Unix server.

Example:
Sample:

```
ABC DE FGH IJKL 04012022.csv
ABC DE FGH IJKL 04022022.csv
```

Expected Output:

```
ABC_DE_FGH_IJKL_04012022.csv
ABC_DE_FGH_IJKL_04022022.csv
```

This is what I tried. But got an error in the mv command as it was trying to rename both files at once.

```
for file in ls ABC\ DE\ FGH\ IJKL\ ????????.csv 
do 
    #Extracting date part separately 
    date_part=$(ls ABC\ DE\ FGH\ IJKL\ ????????.csv | cut -c 17-24) 
    #Appending date part to file 
    csv_file_nm="ABC_DE_FGH_IJKL_"$date_part.csv 
    #Renaming file using mv command 
    mv ABC\ DE\ FGH\ IJKL\ ????????.csv $csv_file_nm 
done
```

Comment: And what is your question? Assuming the script does not work as expected, you should [edit] your question and show the actual output/result/behavior and/or the error message(s) you get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code shown is horribly broken:

```sh
for file in ls ABC\ DE\ FGH\ IJKL\ ????????.csv 
do 
    #Extracting date part separately 
    date_part=$(ls ABC\ DE\ FGH\ IJKL\ ????????.csv | cut -c 17-24) 
    #Appending date part to file 
    csv_file_nm="ABC_DE_FGH_IJKL_"$date_part.csv 
    #Renaming file using mv command 
    mv ABC\ DE\ FGH\ IJKL\ ????????.csv $csv_file_nm 
done
```

To use this idea (which isn't a very good way of proceeding, but…), you'd need to use `"$file"` in the loop rather than repeated `ls` operations:

```sh
for file in ABC\ DE\ FGH\ IJKL\ ????????.csv 
do 
    #Extracting date part separately 
    date_part=$(echo "$file" | cut -c 17-24) 
    #Appending date part to file 
    csv_file_nm="ABC_DE_FGH_IJKL_$date_part.csv" 
    #Renaming file using mv command 
    mv "$file" "$csv_file_nm"
done
```

That script uses globbing rather than `ls` to generate the file names — I've removed a stray `ls` from the `for` line.  You might have intended to write for `file in $(ls …)`, or maybe for `` file in `ls …` ``  — but that isn't in the question. Processing the output of `ls` is not recommended either.

However, since you want to replace the spaces with underscores, a more direct way of operating would be:

```sh
for file in ABC\ DE\ FGH\ IJKL\ ????????.csv 
do 
    csv_file_nm=$(echo "$file" | sed 's/ /_/g') 
    mv "$file" "$csv_file_nm" 
done
```

Or, if your shell is Bash (and new enough), then:

```sh
for file in ABC\ DE\ FGH\ IJKL\ ????????.csv 
do 
    mv "$file" "${file// /_}" 
done
```

Or, if you have the Perl-based `rename` (sometimes called `prename`) command on the system, then:

```sh
rename 's/ /_/g' "ABC DE FGH IJKL "????????.csv
```